# How to cut out matched string

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to cut out string matched.

I consider using "[m.start() for m in re.finditer('')]" for get index.

But I think exist better way than this.

For example, I want to cut out string between "header" and "footer".

```
str = "header1svdijfooter1ccsdheader2cdijhfooter2"
headers = ["one": "header1", "two": "header2"]
footers = ["one": "footer1", "two": "footer2"]

#I want to get ["header1svdijfooter1", "header2cdijhfooter2"]
```

Please advice me.

Comment: please edit your post to fix the `headers` and `footers`. declaring them this way is a compile error http://pastebin.com/pPNHvJEe Did you mean to create a dictionary? use `dict()` or `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def returnmatches(text,headers,footers):
    """headers is a list of headers
footers is a list of footers
text is the text to search"""
    for header,footer in zip(headers,footers):
        pattern = r"{}\w+?{}".format(header,footer)
        try:
            yield re.search(pattern,input_text).group()
        except AttributeError:
            # handle no match
            pass
```

Or alternatively:

```
text = "header1svdijfooter1ccsdheader2cdijhfooter2"
headers = ["header1", "header2"]
footers = ["footer1", "footer2"]

import re

matches = [re.search(r"{}\w+?{}".format(header,footer),text).group() for header,footer in zip(headers,footers) if re.search(r"{}\w+?{}".format(header,footer),text)]
```

Comment: There's no mention of whitespace being special in the match?

Comment: @dementedhedgehog his example doesn't have any whitespace in the string so I didn't want to include anything he didn't explicitly mention in his example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

# as a general rule you shouldn't call variables str in python as it's a builtin function name.
str = "header1svdijfooter1ccsdheader2cdijhfooter2" 

# this is how you declare dicts.. but if you're only going to have "one"
# and "two" for the keys why not use a list?  (you need the {} for dicts).
#headers = {"one": "header1", "two": "header2"}  
#footers = {"one": "footer1", "two": "footer2"}  
delimiters = [("header1", "footer1"), ("header2", "footer2")]

results = []
for header, footer in delimiters:

    regex = re.compile("({header}.*?{footer})".format(header = header, footer = footer))

    matches = regex.search(str)
    if matches is not None:
        for group in matches.groups():
            results.append(group)

print results
```

Comment: this is a good use of regular expression. would you consider editing your answer to contain a formatted string, and not use the `%` format operator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 0):

The calculation can be done in one line using a list comprehension:

```
s = "header1svdijfooter1ccsdheader2cdijhfooter2"
headers = {"one": "header1", "two": "header2"}
footers = {"one": "footer1", "two": "footer2"}
out = [re.search('({}.*?{})'.format(headers[k], footers[k]), s).group(0) for k in sorted(headers.keys())]
```

The above assumes, as per the example, that there is one and only one matching group.

Alternatively, if one prefers looping:

```
s = "header1svdijfooter1ccsdheader2cdijhfooter2"
headers = {"one": "header1", "two": "header2"}
footers = {"one": "footer1", "two": "footer2"}
out=[]
for k in sorted(headers.keys()):
    out.extend(re.search('({}.*?{})'.format(headers[k], footers[k]), s).groups())
print out
```

The above produces the output:

```
['header1svdijfooter1', 'header2cdijhfooter2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Without re:

```
str = "header1svdijfooter1ccsdheader2cdijhfooter2"
result = []
capture=False
currentCapture = ""
for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i:].startswith("header1") or str[i:].startswith("header2"):
        currentCapture = ""
        capture=True
    elif str[:i].endswith("footer1") or str[:i].endswith("footer2"):
        capture=False
        result.append(currentCapture)
        currentCapture = ""
    if capture:
        currentCapture = currentCapture+str[i]
if currentCapture:
    result.append(currentCapture)

print result
```

Output:

```
['header1svdijfooter1', 'header2cdijhfooter2']
```